# Save and read AppSetting from Access File with password in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, appsettings

I have class which read and save AppSetting from text file. Now I want to change the txt file to Access File with password. The problem is I don't know how to write it. Here is my code:

```
public static string HashKey = "hometelaccess";
    static readonly string filePath = Application.StartupPath + "/Server.txt";
    public static string GetValue(string key)
    {
        key = key.ToLower();
        List<KeyValue> lstKeyValue = GetLstKeyValue();
        return lstKeyValue.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == key)?.Value.Decrypt(HashKey);
    }
    private static List<KeyValue> GetLstKeyValue()
    {
        List<KeyValue> lstKeyValue = new List<KeyValue>();
        List<string> lstLine = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList();
        foreach (var line in lstLine)
        {
            string[] strTmp = line.Split(','); 
            lstKeyValue.Add(new KeyValue { Key = strTmp[0], Value = strTmp[1] });
        }
        return lstKeyValue;
    }
    public static void SaveToConfig(string key, string value)
    {
        key = key.ToLower();
        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
            File.Create(filePath);
        List<KeyValue> lstKeyValue = GetLstKeyValue();
        KeyValue keyValue = lstKeyValue.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == key);
        if (keyValue == null)
            lstKeyValue.Add(new KeyValue { Key = key, Value = value.Encrypt(HashKey) });
        else keyValue.Value = value.Encrypt(HashKey);
        File.WriteAllLines(filePath, lstKeyValue.Select(x => x.Key + "," + x.Value));
    }
}
```

My problem is I really don't know how to connect this Access File which has password and how to read from it.

Answer (score 0):

I finally find way so I think I would be good to share it

```
 public static string HashKey = "hometelaccess";


    public static string GetValue(string key)
    {
        key = key.ToLower();
        List<KeyValue> lstKeyValue = GetLstKeyValue();
        return lstKeyValue.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == key)?.Value.Decrypt(HashKey);
    }

    private static List<KeyValue> GetLstKeyValue()
    {

            List<KeyValue> lstKeyValue = new List<KeyValue>();
            var conectstring = $"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={Application.StartupPath + "/DataString.mdb"};Jet OLEDB:Database Password =123987741963;";
            try
            {
                using (OleDbConnection conection = new OleDbConnection())
                {
                    using (OleDbCommand ocm = new OleDbCommand())
                    {
                        conection.ConnectionString = conectstring;
                        conection.Open();
                        ocm.Connection = conection;


                        OleDbDataAdapter command = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Tbl_Config]", conection);

                        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
                        command.Fill(dt);

                        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            lstKeyValue.Add(new KeyValue { Key = row["Key"].ToString(), Value = row["Value"].ToString() });

                        }

                        conection.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }

            return lstKeyValue;
        }

    public static void SaveToConfig(string key, string value)
    {
        key = key.ToLower();

        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
            File.Create(filePath);

        List<KeyValue> lstKeyValue = GetLstKeyValue();
        var conectstring = $"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={Application.StartupPath + "/Datastring.mdb"};Jet OLEDB:Database Password =123987741963;";
        try
        {
            using (OleDbConnection conection = new OleDbConnection())
            {
                using (OleDbCommand ocm = new OleDbCommand())
                {
                    conection.ConnectionString = conectstring;

                    ocm.Connection = conection;

                    conection.Open();
                    KeyValue keyValue = lstKeyValue.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == key);
                    if (keyValue == null)
                    {
                       var x= ocm.CommandText = "Insert Into [Tbl_Config] ([Key] , [Value]) VALUES(?,?)";       
                        ocm.Parameters.AddWithValue("key", key);
                        ocm.Parameters.AddWithValue("Value", value.Encrypt(HashKey));

                        ocm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        ocm.CommandText = "UPDATE [Tbl_Config] SET [Value]=? where [Key]=?";                           
                        ocm.Parameters.Add("@Value", OleDbType.LongVarWChar).Value = value.Encrypt(HashKey);
                        ocm.Parameters.Add("@key", OleDbType.LongVarWChar).Value = key;
                        ocm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }


                    conection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

    }
```